# Unable to insert 1 record through sql loader

Tags: sql-loader

I'm trying to load around 289150 records through SQL loader, out of which 1 record is failing to insert and I'm getting the below error. Pasting the record for which it is failing and the error which is recorded.
record for which it is failing:- `200511734,"동발"사향만응고(ALL-MuschusPlaster),`

Error message:- `no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field`

CTL file details

```
options(PARALLEL = TRUE, DIRECT = TRUE, skip=1)
UNRECOVERABLE LOAD DATA
APPEND INTO TABLE TEST_1234
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS

(
Item_serial_number char(1000),
Item_name char(4000)

)
```

want to know if there any issue in how we are loading the data or is it a data issue

Answer (score 0):

This response is based on the information you have supplied in the question. Prima facie, this is simple error and does not require any specialist support. Your input is

```
200511734,"동발"사향만응고(ALL-MuschusPlaster)
```

but should be

```
200511734,"동발""사향만응고(ALL-MuschusPlaster)",
```

or

```
200511734,"동발",사향만응고(ALL-MuschusPlaster),
```

The error is due to missing comma or double quote symbol after  `"동발"` because in your `CTL` you are specifying delimiters of `"` or `,` at `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`.

So, it's basically the data error.